# Python Regex Alternative

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the following language:

```
L = {a^nb^m | (n+m) is even }
```

That is, n a's followed by m b's so that (n+m) is even. I build the following regex

```
((aa)*(bb)*)|(a(aa)*b(bb)*)
```

but it only ever matches the first part of the alternative, not the second (tested with https://regex101.com/r/c5HucF/1/). It won't match aaabbb. When I remove the first alternative, leaving me only with (a(aa)*b(bb)*), aaabbb is matched just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the main criteria here is that n+m is an even number, therefor you could try:

```
^(?=(?:..)+$)a+b+$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX787D/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?=` - Positive lookahead:

  - `(?:` - Non capture group:

    - `..` - Any two characters other than newline.
    - `)+$` - Close non-capture group and match 1+ time up to end string.
  - `)` - Close positive lookahead.
- `a+b+` - 1+ times an "a" and 1+ times a "b".
- `$` - End string anchor.

I guess you could change the `+` in `a+b+` into an `*` if you would wish to match "bb" to where "a^0" would be considered valid input.

Comment: Awesome, that works. But do you have any idea why my code above does not work? What am I missing about the "alternative" operator?

Comment: @fabian; you have forgotten about the start/end-string anchors. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/IvCV8Z/1) is a working example using non-capturing groups instead of capture groups too.

Comment: JvdV: I am still somewhat confused as to what exactly solved my expression from above. It seems that the "most important" change from mine to your expression was from * to + in the first "alternative". That is: ((aa)*(bb)*)|(a(aa)*b(bb)*) -> ((aa)+(bb)+)|(a(aa)*b(bb)*). As a consequence, the expression from your last comment does not match bb anymore (https://regex101.com/r/IvCV8Z/2).

Comment: it would if you change the "+" to a "*" quantifier, otherwise the expression would expect at least a single "a". See [this](https://regex101.com/r/slKq5q/1). Now the issue is that there can also be absolutely nothing. An empty string get's validates. Theorethically it maches your conditions but you then need to include a test to prevent an empty string if this is not what you are after. Either way.....go with the easier solution I mentioned in the answer =)

Comment: I see. Thanks again! An empty string is fine.